# Python can't encode with surrogateescape

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I have a problem with Unicode surrogates encoding in Python (3.4):

```
>>> b'\xCC'.decode('utf-16_be', 'surrogateescape').encode('utf-16_be', 'surrogateescape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-16-be' codec can't encode character '\udccc' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

If I'm not mistaken, according to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers):

> 'surrogateescape': On decoding, replace byte with individual surrogate
>   code ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. This code will then be turned back
>   into the same byte when the 'surrogateescape' error handler is used
>   when encoding the data.

The code should just produce the source sequence (`b'\xCC'`). So why is the exception raised instead?

This is possibly related to my second question:

> Changed in version 3.4: The utf-16* and utf-32* encoders no longer allow surrogate code points (U+D800–U+DFFF) to be encoded.

(From https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

From as far as I know, it's impossible to encode some code points to UTF-16 without surrogate pairs. So what's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This change was made because the *Unicode standard* explicitly disallows such encodings. See [issue #12892](http://bugs.python.org/issue12892), but apparently the `surrogateescape` error handler cannot be made to work with UTF-16 or UTF-32, because these codecs are not ASCII compatible.

Specifically:

> I tested utf_16_32_surrogates_4.patch: surrogateescape with as encoder
>   does not work as expected.
>
> ```
> >>> b'[\x00\x80\xdc]\x00'.decode('utf-16-le', 'ignore')
> '[]'
> >>> b'[\x00\x80\xdc]\x00'.decode('utf-16-le', 'replace')
> '[�]'
> >>> b'[\x00\x80\xdc]\x00'.decode('utf-16-le', 'surrogateescape')
> '[\udc80\udcdc\uffff'
> ```
>
> => I expected `'[\udc80\udcdc]'`.

to which came the response:

> Yes, surrogateescape doesn't work with ASCII incompatible encodings and can't. First, it can't represent the result of decoding `b'\x00\xd8'` from utf-16-le or `b'ABCD'` from utf-32*. This problem is worth separated issue (or even PEP) and discussion on Python-Dev.

I believe the `surrogateescape` handler was more meant for UTF-8 data; that decoding to UTF-16 or UTF-32 works with it too now is a nice extra but it can't work in the other direction, apparently.

Comment: Why `surrogateescape` can't work with ASCII non-compatible encodings? Also, you point "First, it can't represent the result of decoding `b'\x00\xd8'`" but according to PEP 383 this is not a correct lone surrogate, and in my example the `.decode()` method produces correct lone surrogate, so `.encode()` should be able to recreate `b'\xCC'`.

Comment: @m4tx: to be honest, I don't buy the explanation given in the ticket, I've poked the developers to provide a better explanation. `b'\x80'` -> `'\udc80'` -> `b'\x80'` seems perfectly round-tripable to me, unless the UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoders have trouble with code units that don't fit the normal 2-byte or 4-byte pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `surrogatepass` (instead of `surrogateescape`), things should work on Python 3.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes (which says that `surrogatepass` allows encoding and decoding of surrogate codes (for `utf` related encoding).